# What is the logic of this code and how does it work so fast?

Tags: python, prime-factoring

New to Python and was trying to solve a challenge to find prime factors for large numbers. I soon ran into a roadblock with the logic I was going for. Broadly speaking, my logic was:

1. Find the factors for a given number and store them in a list
2. From that list, evaluate each number to check if prime, and if prime
   store in a new list

So after #2 I would have a list of primes that were factors of the original number. Got stuck after I realized, I would have to determine the combination of elements in this second list that would make up the original number because all the elements although prime, couldn't necessarily be multiplied with each other to get the original number.

Anyway, after struggling for quite a bit I found the following code that helped with the function I was trying to create.

```
def prime_factors(n):
    # Returns all the prime factors of a positive integer
    factors = []
    d = 2
    while n > 1:
        while n % d == 0: #if no remainder
            factors.append(d)
            n /= d
        d = d + 1
        if d*d > n:
            if n > 1: factors.append(n)
            break
    return factors

pfs = prime_factors(600851475143)
print(pfs)
total = sum(pfs)
```

and gives output

```
[71, 839, 1471, 6857]
```

Needed some help understanding how this works and also how this is so fast with a 9 digit number. My previous attempts with some logic that either didn't work or would have my command prompt in hang state trying to calculate for the prime factors this big.

Comment: Specifically what have you done to understand the code, and which part don't you understand? Working through the code on small examples (eg: n=12, n=15, n=16, n1=17) would, I think, be all that's needed to understand it.

Comment: The main idea is using the [Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) which states: `Any integer greater than 1 is either a prime number, or can be written as a unique product of prime numbers (ignoring the order)` . Look [here](http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-problem-3/) for more informations.

Comment: Maybe post your code. Things that might make this faster than yours: only check up to sqrt, and divide out the factors when found. Of course, it also seems fast because most numbers have several fairly small prime factors, making it easy to narrow down the problem. Try it on cryptographic primes, and it may never find a single factor.

Comment: One thing that makes this much faster than naive trial factoring is that it recognizes that once we've found a factor, we can remove it from 'n' and now we're factoring a smaller number.  Basically every time you find a factor, you recalculate n and sqrt(n).  It's still trial division so won't scale, as Kenny pointed out.  If there are no small factors it will still take increasingly long even if you add more optimizations (e.g. wheel factoring).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fast because it is using a **primality test**, [an interesting topic](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimalityTest.html).

Keep reading for another solution much simpler for newcomers,

This function will check whether the given integer **n** is prime or not, when we divide n by **i** (which is initialized to 2), if the result is 0, the result will be False, because a prime number can only be divided by 1 or itself, if not, **i** will be incremented (increased) by 1, if **i** is finally equal to **n**, the result will be True, because the result of the division of **n** by **i** doesn't equal to 0.

```
def prime(n):
    for i in range(2,n):   # letting i have multiple values starting from 2
        if n % i == 0:     # checking the remainder, if it's 0, then n is not prime,
            return False   # and so False will be returned,
        else:
            i += 1   # if n is still considered prime, i will become 3, then 4, and so on
                     # until it becomes equal to n
    return True      # if so, then n is prime, so True will be returned
```

Here we will have an empty list called **factors** in which we will store the prime factors, now take a look at the 4th line, you will see notice that: if **n % i == 0** and **i** is prime, we will add it to our list called **factors**, we will do that only and only if the two expressions below are True, if the division of **n** by **i** doesn't equal to 0 *OR/AND* **i** is not prime (meaning prime(i) returned False), we will not then add **i** to our list, note that **i** in this function *prime_factors* is an integer which will be verified to be a factor of **n** and be prime too.

```
def prime_factors(n):
    factors = [] #initializing an empty list that will soon be modified
    for i in range(2,n):
        if (n % i == 0) and (prime(i)): # if i is a factor of n and also i is prime
            factors.append(i)           # the values will be added to our list named factors
    return factors   # this list contains the prime factors values which, we return it
```

Giving **n** a value and then showing the prime factors

```
n = 81210459 # the value of n
pfs = prime_factors(n) # storing our list returned from this function is the variable pfs
print("prime factors of",n,"are:",pfs) # showing the results (this is obvious isn't it :D)
```

Output:

```
Prime factors of 81210459 are: [3, 11, 61, 40343]
```